# Maximising sharpe of portfolio with equal weights

Tags: portfolio-optimization

I want to maximise $\frac{w^T\mu}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}$ with $w_i$ either 0 or $\frac{1}{\#\text{nonzero weights}}$.

This is the same as maximising $\frac{\tilde{w}^T\mu}{\sqrt{\tilde{w}^T\Sigma \tilde{w}}}$ with $\tilde{w} \in \{0, 1\}^N$, then setting $w:=\frac{\tilde{w}}{||\tilde{w}||}$.

I've tried looking at some transformations of the problem to try solve with `cvxopt` (which supports binary programming), but no success.

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't the solution trivial in this case? $w_i = w_j = 1/N$? 
Where N is the number of assets

Comment: Oops - you are correct, I meant that $w_i$ is either $0$ or $\frac{1}{\# \text{nonzero weights}}$.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/find-k-of-n-assets-that-minimize-the-correlation-matrix/65689#65689 You'd only need a different objective function (instead of `mean_cor`).

Comment: This is just a heuristic, I think, but worth a try - thanks.